# Group by on same table and include all data like names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table and fictional records in my database.

```
id | name         | status | clientid 
1  | John Doe     | 4      | 200
2  | Jane Doe     | 2      | 400
3  | John Doe     | 4      | 200
4  | Mike Smith   | 4      | 300
5  | Mike Smith   | 2      | 300
6  | Jane Doe     | 4      | 400
7  | Jane Doe     | 4      | 400
```

What I'd like to do is retrieve all the records, grouped by `clientid` and show some statusses
for those records. For example, I want to know how many statuses `clientid` 400 has set to status `2` and how many he has on status `4`.

So I'd like to have an ouput that looks like  this:

```
id | name         | clientid | status_2 | status_4
1  | John Doe     | 200      | 0        | 2
2  | Mike Smith   | 300      | 1        | 1
3  | Jane Doe     | 400      | 1        | 2
```

But I can't figure out how to get this. When I do a `GROUP BY` then I can't get their names to show. When I do a `LEFT JOIN` then I get to many records back etc.

How should I build the query to get results like the one above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select name, 
       clientid, 
       sum(case when status = 2 then 1 end) as status_2,
       sum(case when status = 4 then 1 end) as status_4
from your_table
group by name,
         clientid
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy part is conditional aggregation.  If you really want an `id` that increments like that, then you can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by min(id)) as id,
       name, clientid,
       sum(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as status_2,
       sum(case when status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as status_4
from table t
group by name, clientid;
```